# Cómo obtener el valor del menor flotante en una lista o array usando C

Tags: c

Muy buen dia tengan ustedes... como dice en el titulo de la publicacion tengo  una duda ya que debo realizar un programa que solicite los valores FLOTANTES de las celdas de una matriz de 3 x 3, con el siguiente menú de opciones:

1. Capturar la matriz
2. Mostrar la matriz después de haberse capturado
3. La suma de los elementos de la matriz
4. El valor menor
5. Salir

Me falta el punto 4 pero en verdad que no tengo idea de como desarrollarlo soy principiante, ya he buscado tutoriales sobre matrices en youtube pero no logro dar con lo que se me solicita y es por eso que me encuentro aqui, pidiendo ayuda a ustedes...
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float matriz[3][3];
int fila, columna, opc;
int sum=0;

int main ()
{
    do{
    //menu
    printf("\nMENU\n");

printf("\n1. Capturar la matriz");
    printf("\n2. Mostrar matriz capturada");
    printf("\n3. Suma de los elementos de la matriz");
    printf("\n4. Valor menor");
    printf("\n5. Salir");


     printf("\n\nQue deseas hacer?\n");
      scanf("%i", &opc);
switch (opc){
    case 1:

//registrar los valores de la matriz
printf("Da los valores de la matriz: \n");
for(fila=0;fila<=2;fila++)
    for(columna=0;columna<=2;columna++)
    scanf("%f", &matriz[fila][columna]);
    break;

    case 2:
//imprimir los valores de la matriz
printf("\nla captura de datos queda como: \n\n");
for(fila=0; fila<=2; fila++)
{
    for(columna=0;columna<=2;columna++)
        printf(" %.1f ", matriz[fila][columna]);
        printf("\n");
}
         break;

//suma de los elementos de la matriz
        case 3:
            for(fila=0;fila<=2;fila++)
    for(columna=0;columna<=2;columna++)
    sum += matriz[fila][columna];
        printf("\nLa suma de los elementos de la matriz es: %i \n\n", sum); 

        break;


//duda
        case 4:

        break;

//salir del ciclo
        case 5:
        break;


default:
break;
}

}while(opc!=5);



getchar();

}
```

de antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido [es.so], te invito a leer [ask]. Tu pregunta está bastante aceptable. Yo cambiaría el título por algo más sugerente: ***Cómo obtener el valor del menor flotante en una lista o array usando C***, tal vez eso llamará más la atención que tu título actual. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero que uses `{}` para encerrar los bucles `for`. Eso hace tu código más legible.

Puedes tener algo como:

```
case 1:
  //registrar los valores de la matriz
  printf("Ingresa los valores de la matriz: \n");
  for(fila = 0;fila < 3; fila++) {
    for(columna = 0;columna < 3; columna++) {
      printf("Fila %d, Columna %d: ", fila, columna);
      scanf("%f", &matriz[fila][columna]);
    }
  }
  break;
```

Otra sugerencia es que uses límites excluyentes en tus bucles `for`, actualmente tienes algo como:

```
for(fila = 0; fila <= 2; fila++) { ... }
```

Mi sugerencia es que lo cambies por:

```
for(fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++) { ... }
```

Así el `upperbound` o límite superior del bucle es excluyente. Esto no es una regla, solo una especie de norma no escrita. Y en todo caso es una opinión.

En cuanto a tu duda, debes realizar una comparación de cada elemento de la matriz, esto significa que debes recorrerla toda.

Primero debemos crear una variable que almacenará el menor elemento (flotante) de nuestra matriz. La llamaremos `menor`:

```
float menor;
```

Dado que los elementos de la matriz son de tipo `Float`, la variable que almacena la suma debe ser tipo `Float` también. Actualmente la tienes declarada como `Integer`. Debes declararla así:

```
float sum = 0;
```

Lo que debes hacer es escoger el primer elemento de tu matriz como el elemento menor, y desde ese punto empiezas a comparar. Al recorrer el bucle irás actualizando el valor de la variable `menor` en caso de que consigas un elemento menor al que ya está almacenado.

Una forma de implementarlo sería la siguiente:

```
// Buscamos el menor elemento de la matriz
case 4:
  menor = matriz[0][0]; // establecemos el primer elemento de la matriz como menor
  for(fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++) {
      for(columna = 0; columna < 3; columna++) {
        // Aqui comparamos, si el elemento de la matriz es menor que el almacenado
        // actualizamos el valor de 'menor' con el elemento de la matriz
        if(matriz[fila][columna] < menor) {
          menor = matriz[fila][columna];
        }
      }
    }
    printf("\nEl menor elemento flotante es: %.4f\n", menor);
    break;
```

Con esto ya tienes una forma de capturar el menor elemento de tu matriz.

Una corrida del programa completo puede verse aquí:

[image: Ejemplo de corrida del programa]

He resaltado el resultado del valor menor, puedes ver en la parte superior de la imagen los valores que fueron introducidos a la matriz.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho!!.